# Sal Maroni's fate in the Nolan Batman trilogy

Tags: the-dark-knight

The last we see of *Sal Maroni* in [*The Dark Knight*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/) is the car flipping over. IIRC there is no further mention of him in the film or in [*The Dark Knight Rises*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1345836/) either. Has there been any E.U mention of him?

Comment: What is *"E.U"*? Other than that, I think he's implied to get killed in the car crash (however *Harvey* survived that is unclear, though). *"You're lucky...he not"* - *"Who?"* - *"Your driver!"*.

Comment: expanded universe . e.g novelisation

Answer (score 3):

His fate in the movie is [intentionally left as ambiguous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sal_Maroni#Film), but there's some implying by Jim Gordon later that Harvey killed five people, so Maroni could be one of the five.

However, in the comics (specifically [Batman: The Long Halloween](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%3a_The_Long_Halloween), which served as influence in some ways for the Batman films directed by Nolan) Maroni is the one responsible for disfiguring Harvey Dent and turning him into Two-Face. [Eventually he's killed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sal_Maroni#Post-Crisis) by the central antagonist in The Long Halloween.